# Why is there no built-in Set data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, set

Is there anyone who can explain to me why there's no `Set` datatype defined in Haskell?

Sidenote:
I'm only learning Haskell as part of a course on logic in which set theory is very important thus it would be really handy to have the notion of a set in Haskell. Having a list and removing duplicates (and possibly sorting) would result in a set as well but I'm curious if there's a particular reason why it's not built-in?

Comment: **Moderator Note** Comments under this question were mostly noise, or a reaction to noise and they have been removed. Please keep comments constructive and on topic.

Comment: I see answers/comments suggesting the usage of lists instead. a list is not an efficient replacement for set. the time to find an element in an unordered list grows with the size of the list, in a set, is expected to be constant.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As other answers indicate, the question "Why is there no Set data type in Haskell?" is misguided: [there is a Set data type](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html).

If you'd like to know why `Set` isn't "built in" to Haskell, you could be asking one of two things.

- Why is `Set` not part of the [language specification](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/)?
- Why is `Set` not in [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html) (the functions and data types that are imported by default)?

To answer the former, it is because the language is powerful enough to express the idea of a set without needing to bake it in. Being a language with a high emphasis on functional programming, special syntax for tuples and lists is built in, but even simple data types like `Bool` are defined in Prelude.

To answer the latter, well, again, with the emphasis on functional programming, most Haskellers tend to use lists. The list monad represents nondeterministic choice, and by allowing duplicates, you can sort of represent weighted choices.

Note [how similar list comprehension syntax is to set notation](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension). You can always use `Set.fromList` to convert a list into a "real" set, if necessary. As a begrudging shout out to Barry, this would be similar to using Python's `set()` method; Python has list comprehensions as well.

Comment: Technically, `Data.Set` is in GHC, but it's not in either the Haskell 98 or 2010 reports

Comment: @user102008 "in GHC"? It's in the [containers package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers), which is included with the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/), but I'm not sure what you mean by saying it is "in GHC".

Comment: @DanBurton well, the `containers` package _ships_ with GHC, even if you don't get the Platform.

Answer (score 11):

On a more philosophical level --- there can't ever be a strict correspondence between the mathematical concept of a set and a Haskell set implementation. Why not? Well, the type system, for starters. A mathematical set can have anything at all in it: `{x | x is a positive integer, i < 15}` is a set, but so is `{1, tree, ham sandwich}`. In Haskell, a `Set a` will need to hold some particular type. Putting Doubles and Floats into the same set won't typecheck.

As others have said, if you need to do some set-like things and don't mind the type restriction, Data.Set exists. It's not in Prelude because lists are usually more practical. But really, from a language design perspective, it doesn't make sense to think of mathematical sets as one datatype among many. Sets are more fundamental than that. You don't have sets, and numbers, and lists; you have sets of numbers, and sets of lists. The power of recursive types tends to obscure that distinction, but it's still real.

There is a place in Haskell, though, where we define arbitrary collections, and then define functions over those collections. The closest analog of the mathematical concept of sets in Haskell is the type system itself.

Comment: A lot of times, sets in mathematics are considered in the context of a "universe" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics))

Comment: @Zopa: you can still express that using a sum-type.

Comment: It's true, as you say, that "in Haskell, a `Set a` will need to hold some particular type". But the type that `a` is instantiated at could be an existential type, of which `1`, `tree` and `ham sandwich` might very well be members, assuming `tree` and `ham sandwich` are themselves well-typed terms... what you could meaningfully do with such a set I have no idea ;) However I do agree with your conclusion, that _types themselves_ are the closest thing Haskell has to the mathematical notion of sets.

Comment: A `Set` also requires elements to be part of the class `Ord` (except singleton sets).

Comment: as @u0b34a0f6ae pointed out, the bigger issue is that sets require either the `Ord` or `(Hashable, Eq)` constraint, which makes sets less elegant in functional programming than lists (since it's no longer a `Functor` or `Monad`).

Comment: I know I'm 8 years late to the party, but I must expand on user102008's comment and say that that this is misleading. There is no single "mathematical concept of a set" and if we look at the standard definitions of set theories in first order logic, then they hold elements in the domain of discourse or logical term universe. So for your example, a set comprehension of numbers (or anything else in common set theory) eventually boils down to a comprehension over other sets, because everything is defined as a set. E.g. the number 3 is commonly just {{}, {{}}, {{}, {{}}}}.

Comment: A math set, is really a function that returns a bool.

Answer (score 9):

It exists as `Data.Set`. However, as you said, it can be implemented on top of `list` and so is not *necessary* to build up the language which, I think, is why it is in a module rather than being part of the definition of the language itself.

Comment: @DietrichEpp yes but the syntax would be really heavy if you add to write list as an explicit chain of Cons.

Comment: @mb14 `(:) == Cons`; there's just syntactic sugar for explicit finite lists and as wrappers around the various `enum{From}{Then}{To}` functions.